# how i move the rotate icon in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

[image]

this is my code

```
var _changeCanvasIcons = function(side){
        side.hasControlCallback = {
            tr: true,
            mtr: true
        };

        side.controlCallback = {
            tr: function (ctx, left, top, size) {
                var image = new Image(), x, y;

                image.src = 'assets/img/control-icons/delete.png';
                x = left - image.width/2 + size/2;
                y = top - image.height/2 + size/2;

                ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
            },
            mtr: function (ctx, left, top, size) {
                var image = new Image(), x, y;

                image.src = 'assets/img/control-icons/rotate.png';


                ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Explain what exactly you want to move, when, etc

Comment: thanks for reply i want to move from middle top right to top left how i move in middle top righ to top left